# Infer generic types based on expression

Tags: c#, generics, reflection

I am building a DSL in C# using expression trees and one of the challenges I am trying to solve is inferring generic types from an input expression. Here is a contrived example:

```
class GenericThing<T> {
    public List<IOption<T>> solveMe;
}

// given the type of some expression, (and assuming types are assignable to each other)
var someExpression = new List<IOption<string>>();

// call a function that can infer the type of generic arguments from `GenericThing<>`
Type reflected = SolveGenericTypes(typeof(GenericThing<>), "solveMe", someExpression.GetType()));

// use that type to create an instance of GenericThing<string>
object instance = Activator.CreateInstance(reflected);
```

How could I implement `SolveGenericTypes()` to 'solve' for T? (Bonus, also solve for multiple generic arguments) I would need the function to work not just for this case, but basically take any generic type definition and any concrete type (assume there are no typechecking errors) and return a type that can be instantiated.

Edit: more concrete example

The DSL takes in XML nodes and converts it to expression trees that generate UI Elements. One example would be a drop down element that can accept a list of options that is typed but conforms to an interface.

`<Dropdown options="someExpressionReturningIOptionsList"/>`

```
class Dropdown<T> {
    public List<IOption<T>> options;
}
interface IOption<T> {
    string label;
    T value;
}
```

I could then use the dropdown with different data types as follows:

```
<Dropdown options="someListOfStringOptions"/>
<Dropdown options="someListOfLocationOptions"/>
<Dropdown options="someListOfIntOptions"/>
<Dropdown options="someListOfFloatOptions"/>
```

For each of these four usages I'd need to infer the type of `Dropdown<>` to create in my expression tree. I'm looking for a generic (sorry, bad pun) solution to 'infer' generic types based on the options parameter in the xml

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have more than one `GenericThing` with different kinds of fields like that? Or is that the only one? I ask because you will need intimate knowledge about how the types go together. I am assuming you want to figure out that `T` has to be `string` in order to make the `solveMe` field have the right type, but if you have other `GenericThing` lookalikes with different embedded properties, that might be a lot of work. Can you clarify about the scope of your question?

Comment: If all you have to handle is `List<IOption<T>>`, you should basically just dig into the Type object from that to go grab the innermost type, the one inside `IOption<T>`, but if `someExpression` is of type `Dictionary<int, string>`, and you have `ThisOtherGenericThing<T1, T2>` with an embedded dictionary, you're going to have quite different code for handling 1 vs. many.

Comment: Sure, you can do that. `Type.IsGenericTypeDefinition`, `Type.GetGenericArguments`, throw in some recursion and/or generic programming. An actual algorithm would be none too trivial and probably exceeds the scope of an answer, especially if all possible cases have to be taken into account (multiple type parameters, constraints, types implementing multiple interfaces, etc.) I'm not sure a close modeling in C# using generic types is the most convenient approach for this, really -- C# type inference is more grudging, because it has to do it, with many corner cases.

Comment: No it would need to handle any type, so `List<T>`, `Dictionary<T,U>`, `T` would also need to be potentially solved for

Comment: I'm ok if it doesn't solve all cases or conform to generics etc. I already have a type checker that handles all that. I need this function to return me something the type checker can later reject if it happens not to match.